# cakephp pages_controller extends instead of overwrites, is that possible?

Tags: cakephp

I need to add new functionalities into "/cake/libs/controller/pages_controller.php" but I do not want to change it directly because it is part of the core's cakephp, therefor what I did was to copy "pages_controller.php" into "app/controllers/" and then I added new functions but I'm getting some errors like "The action display is not defined in controller PagesController".

Notes:

- /cake/libs/controller/pages_controller.php indeed has function display()
- /app/controllers/pages_controller.php does not have display()

What is the problem? why I'm getting that error?

this is the /app/controllers/pages_controller.php:

```
<?php
class PagesController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Pages';
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Session');
    var $uses = array();

    function display_no_layout() {
        $this->autoLayout = false; // new line
        $path = func_get_args();

        $count = count($path);
        if (!$count) {
            $this->redirect('/');
        }
        $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

        if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
        }
        if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
        }
        if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
            $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
        }
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));
        $this->render(implode('/', $path));
    }
}
```

My /app/config/routers.php:

```
Router::connect('home/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
Router::connect('/successfully', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display_no_layout', 'successfully'));
```

Comment: show /app/controllers/pages_controller.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create

```
/app/controllers/pages_controller.php
```

it **overrides**

```
/cake/libs/controller/pages_controller.php
```

So `display()` needs to be in your PagesController, given you are routing to it. You probably want to keep the `display()` as copied and write something like

```
function display_no_layout() {
    $this->autoLayout = false;
    $this->display();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your app is looking for the `display()` action because of this line in `app/config/routes.php` :

```
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

You are trying to access an action in the pages controller but cake is looking for the `display()` action.

**Edit:** After seeing your `PagesController`, the only possible cause for the error is the `routes.php` file

Comment: yes, I have this:         
Router::connect('home/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));

Router::connect('/successfully', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display_no_layout', 'successfully'));

Comment: @lito do you have the line `Router::connect('/pages/* ...'` ?